# Efficient way to determine if elements in two lists are the same

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am trying to find unique combinations of 4 in a population of 32 choices (496 possibilities) that i then pair up in a matrix (so matrix may be up to 496 by 496 or 25,000 cells). However (using numbers to represent the choices) that means that i have some duplicates (1,2) matched with (3,4) is the same as (1,3) matched with (2,4). What I need to do is find the duplicates (same four choices regardless or order) and mark them as such. I have played around with this and read all i can find. In this question (https://www.csestack.org/compare-two-lists-python-return-non-match-elements/) i got a start. However my lists are different - they look like the elements in list_e and list_f (see code below) which do not show up as duplicates, even though players 2,4,6, and 8 show up in each. Ideally i'd like to find a way to compare list_e and list_f and have them register as duplicates. If i have to reformat the contents of list_e and list_f so that they have the same structure as list_a and list_b that will at least get the job done. However, since i have a lot of comparisons, i'd like to do this the most efficient way possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    if len(list_a) != len(list_b):
        return False
    if set(list_a) == set(list_b):
        return True
    else:
        return False
         
 
list_a = [2, 4, 6, 8]
list_b = [2, 8, 6, 4]

list_c = [(2,4,6,8)]
list_d = [(4,6,2,8)]

list_e = [((2,4),(6,8))]
list_f = [((2,6),(4,8))]
 
if is_identical(list_a, list_b):
    print("Two lists are identical.")
else:
    print("Two lists are different.")

    
if is_identical(list_c, list_d):
    print("Two lists are identical.")
else:
    print("Two lists are different.")

if is_identical(list_e, list_f):
    print("Two lists are identical.")
else:
    print("Two lists are different.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove all brackets sort it and check if the lists are same.

```
a = [((1,2),(3,4))]
b = [((1,3),(2,4))]
from collections import Iterable                            # < py38


def flatten(items):
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
            for sub_x in flatten(x):
                yield sub_x
        else:
            yield x
            
c = (list(flatten(a)))
d = (list(flatten(b)))
print(c.sort()==d.sort()) #True
```

I'll provide some explanation here.

So whats happening is that first you are iterating through the list that is passed in the flatten function.

Then we check if you can iterate through the list  or not by using the isinstance method, for example(syntax) => `isinstance(4, Int)` will give a boolean value i.e `True`

yield gives the value of whatever you wish to return, this is often confused with `return` which only gives a boolean value

This concludes the function, now we just have to flatten the list that you provide, sort it using `.sort()` and compare it.

Comment: Thanks getting some warning about python 3.8 that i'll figure out... How do you learn this stuff, the documentation does not really get into the nuances???

Comment: @steve This answer is valid only if u r using python 3.8, I suggest u install it because it has really good updates. As for learning the syntax I suggest learning the methods individually. U can look up the use of ```isinstance``` - for example. There is enough material available

Comment: @steve I have provided some explanation in my expanded answer and also correct some bracket error in the last few lines, I hope it helps.

Comment: OK - i'll ask, how do i accept your answer. I sure can't see an easy to find button/option.

Comment: @steve The tick mark next to my answer is for accepting it and the arrows are for upvoting or downvoting.